# notify-send - How to display full message when message is longer than one line?

Tags: gnome-shell, notifications, libnotify, notify-send

Let's say I use `notify-send` with this long messages:

```
notify-send 'd: title, up/down: zoom, w: win_to_img, </>: rotate, *: orig, Enter/0: blah blah blah'
```

But it truncates the message, showing only a part of it with no option to view the full message:

[image]

With Fedora 21 I was able to view the full message (pop up at bottom with scrollbar), but not with Fedora 24.

Version of `notify-send` is libnotify-0.7.6-8.fc24.i686.

Is there anyway to display full messages in Fedora 24 ?

Comment: @don_crissti yes, GNOME Shell 3.20.3

Comment: I think that this is related somehow: youtube.com/watch?v=8KMqvAq6WYY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`notify-send` works like this:

```
notify-send [OPTION...] <SUMMARY> [BODY]
```

Now, as you only have one (quoted) string, that's being used for the `SUMMARY` and the `BODY` is empty. Just use blank or whatever for the `SUMMARY` and the `BODY` will display the whole message (but only when you hover over the pop-up with your mouse)<sup>1</sup>:

```
notify-send ' ' 'd: title,up/down: zoom,w: win_to_img,</>: rotate,*: orig,Enter/0: blah blah blah'
```

or if you prefer `gdbus`:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications --object-path \
/org/freedesktop/Notifications --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
my_app_name 42 '' "" 'd: title, up/down: zoom, w: win_to_img, </>: rotate, \
*: orig, Enter/0: your very long message should now span over multiple lines \
and stuf blah blah blah blah whatever...' '[]' '{}' 20
```

---

<sup>1: this is on gnome 3, other DEs might actually display the whole message without the need to hover over it</sup>

Comment: +1.  xfce displays the entire summary over multiple lines, but if you give it a single-space summary and a detailed body, it just pops up an empty (one space) notify box.  mouseover doesn't display the body, either.  the gdbus version does the same.